# How can i access my env variables in android manifest?

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

Im trying to access my Api key from the env file, but i dont really know how to access it, i tried multiple solutions.

here's my build.gradle :

```
defaultConfig { 
manifestPlaceholders = [API_KEY: "$process.env.REACT_NATIVE_PLACES_API_KEY"]
}
```

here's the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="${API_KEY}" />
```

the error i had:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'process'
```

then i tried changing
`$process.env.REACT_NATIVE_PLACES_API_KEY` with `$System.env.REACT_NATIVE_PLACES_API_KEY`

There's no more error, however the map isn't rendering anymore.
unless i use the apikey in string format, so how can i access it as a variable?

Comment: are you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove manifestPlaceholders from the defaultConfig on the build.gradle
`defaultConfig {  manifestPlaceholders = [API_KEY: "$process.env.REACT_NATIVE_PLACES_API_KEY"] }`

Insert the env file `API_KEY=<your value>` and use it in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/API_KEY" />
```